# How to match a int less than 50 in regx

Tags: regex

I want to match a url like "index.html\index_1.html\index_12.html\index_49.html\index_n.html
and the n must <50 not be 50

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using - `index_[1-4]?\d\.html` as your regex.

What this does is it first limits the first digit of two to the numbers 1-4 then accepts any other following digit. The `?` makes it so that the digit may be skipped if it cannot be found

regex101 link - https://regex101.com/r/BwMCdu/1 which has a few examples

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
(((index)|(index_[0-9])|(index_[0-4][0-9])).html)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [1-4]?[0-9]

index.html\index_1.html\index_12.html\index_49.html\index_[0-4]?[0-9].html$